# JQuery - Why do I get "target is not defined"

Tags: jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{ 
    $(".menubutton").click(function()
        { 
        var $id=$(event.target.id.substring(0,2));
        $(".active").animate({"top": "-=1000px"}, speedanim);
        $("div#homedrawer div").filter($(".active")).removeClass("active");
        $("#"+$id).animate({"top": "+=1000px"}, speedanim);
        $("#"+$id).addClass("active");
        return false; 
        });

});
```

The above code generates this error "target is not defined" referring to the line:

```
var $id=$(event.target.id.substring(0,2));
```

this is the HTML:

```
<a id="fesbtn" class="menubutton" href="#"><img src="img/menu/fes.png" alt="" /></a>
<a id="futbtn" class="menubutton" href="#"><img src="img/menu/fut.png" alt="" /></a>
<a id="reibtn" class="menubutton" href="#"><img src="img/menu/rei.png" alt="" /></a>
...
```

obviously my syntax is wrong. Any thoughts? thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

event is missing as an argument of your click handler

Comment: thank you! in case anyone needs further clarification I changed the first line thus: `$(".menubutton").click(function(event)`

Answer (score 0):

event is not defined

also javascript variables should not start with $

Answer (score 0):

If what you're trying to do is get the id of the button that was clicked, then replace this:

```
var $id=$(event.target.id.substring(0,2));
```

with this:

```
var $id = this.id.substring(0,2);
```

Use `this` to refer to the object that generated the event.  Much easier than reaching into the event object which you haven't defined (which is why you were getting a JS error).

From the rest of your code, it also looks like you just want `$id` to be a string.  If that's the case, then do not try to make a jQuery object out of it.  Do you realize that you're only getting a 2 character string here?  It looks like you might have three unique characters in the button IDs.