# offset() from jQuery crashes on "elem.getClientRects is not a function"

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
const targetPos = target.offset();
```

I am getting this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: elem.getClientRects is not a function
```

The target is not a window. jQuery version is 3.2.1 and I am **not** using jQuery UI.

Any ideas why is it crashing and how to fix it?

Comment: add the html code to reproduce this issue

Comment: So what is `target` ?

Comment: It's a part of an Angular application, it won't be easy to create a test :(.

Comment: If you console.log `target`, what do you get

Comment: Please refer to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7657112/jquery-why-do-i-get-target-is-not-defined][1]

Comment: @TranAudi That doesn't seem relevant at all.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, it turns out `target` was a wrong object (@adeneo was probably suspecting this).

When passing it to a function which expects the `target` I forgot that `ElementRef` (`element` field) is not actually the DOM element I wanted, it's just a wrapper.

I changed

```
jQuery(angularComponent.element)
```

to

```
jQuery(angularComponent.element.nativeElement)
```

and now it works :).